# For the expectation of a continuous random variable $X$, why cannot both $\int^\infty_0 xf_X \, dx$ and $\int^0_{-\infty} xf_X\,dx$ equal $\infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

My lecturer wrote:

The expected value of a continuous random variable $X$ is:

$$E(X)= \int^\infty_{-\infty}xf_X\,dx$$

Provided that not both

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 xf_X \, dx \quad \text{and} \quad \int_0^\infty xf_X \, dx$$

equal $\infty$.

My lecturer stated that it was to ensure that $\infty - \infty$ does not occur. Though I don't see how this would happen.

Since if they both were to equal $\infty$ we would get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int^\infty_{-\infty}xf_X\,dx & =\int_{-\infty}^0 xf_X \, dx + \int_0^\infty xf_X \, dx \\
& = \infty + \infty \\
& = \infty.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Can you please state where I am wrong, whether the condition is not needed or if there is another reason why the condition is required.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: on $(-\infty,0)$ function $x \to xf_X(x)$ is negative (almost surely) so the integral $\int_{-\infty}^0 xf_X(x)dx$ if diverges, it diverges to $-\infty$ (and this is what probably your lecturer had in mind by saying both are $\infty$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place if $f$ is a non-negative function, then $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^0 x f(x)\,dx <0.$

Note that $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx/\pi}{1+x^2} = 1$ and the function being integrated is everywhere positive.

Then $\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} x \cdot \frac{dx/\pi}{1+x^2} = +\infty$ and $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^0 x\cdot \frac{dx/\pi}{1+x^2} = -\infty.$

One problem with allowing both the positive and negative parts to be infinite is that rearrangements can alter the value of an integral; for example:
$$
\lim_{a\,\to\,\infty} \int_{-a}^{+a} x\cdot\frac{dx/\pi}{1+x^2} = 0 \ne \frac 1 {2\pi} \log_e2 = \lim_{a\,\to\,\infty} \int_{-a}^{+2a} x\cdot\frac{dx/\pi}{1+x^2}.
$$
Another is that a bunch of standard theorems such as the weak law of large numbers do not hold for distributions like $\dfrac{dx/\pi}{1+x^2}$ in which the negative and positive parts of the integral that would otherwise give the expected value are infinite.